# Module installed but still receiving ImportError 'No module named docopt'

Tags: python

I installed the module docopt i.e: `pip install --user docopt`. However if I execute the script I receive an ImportError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "compare_files.py", line 19, in <module>
    from docopt import docopt
ImportError: No module named docopt
```

I listed the installed modules and docopt is there:
`pip list`

> docopt (0.6.2)

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from docopt import docopt
import os
import sys
import re
import csv
import difflib

def main():
    print("This line will be printed.")
main ()
```

This line will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

type this it will work

```
pip install docopt
```

Then

```
from docopt import *
```

or

```
import docopt
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I receive the same ImportError